# Using explode() function break string with 2 spaces into two variable?

Tags: php

This is my code, currently I am able to break it into two variable successfully

```
$string="life really";
list($firstName, $lastName) = explode(" ", $string);
echo $firstName;  
echo $lastName;
```

the output will be like

```
life
really
```

This is my second try

```
$string="life really suck";
list($firstName, $lastName) = explode(" ", $string);
echo $firstName;  
echo $lastName;
```

it only echo first and last word in the string

which is life and suck, it didn't capture "really suck" in the $lastname

What I wanted to do is, I want to capture the first word in the $firstname and capture the whatever after the first spacing and place in the $lastname.

Is it possible?

Comment: Why are you using list() ?

Comment: @SkarXa IMHO this is a perfectly good example of using function [`list`](http://se2.php.net/manual/en/function.list.php)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [the PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php), `explode` has an optional third parameter that specifies a *limit* for how many elements the function can return. Using this limit, you can make the function put the first match in the first element and the rest of the string in the second element.

Example:

```
$string="life really suck";
list($firstName, $lastName) = explode(" ", $string, 2); // Added argument 2
echo $firstName;
echo $lastName;
```

http://ideone.com/Vu0GUz

Answer (score 1):

This provides a correct solution: given a string like "A B C D ..." will return 2 variables:

$v1 = "A"; $v2 = "B C D ...";

here's the code.

```
$string="life really suck a lot";
$parts = explode(" ", $string);
$v1 = array_shift($parts);
$v2 = implode(" ", $parts);
```

output:

$v1 = "life"

$v2 = "really suck a lot";

Comment: I would use `$v1 = array_shift($parts);`

Comment: @HeinAndréGrønnestad thanks, i didn't know that function before now

Comment: "life really suck a lot" :D

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$string="life really suck";
preg_match("/(?P<firstname>\w+) (?P<lastname>.*)/",$string,$match);

extract($match);
echo $firstname;
echo "<br>";
echo $lastname;
```

Comment: Wow, a regex! nice but overkill :D (PS: I'm a fan of the saying "There's no such thing as too much firepower", anyway)

Comment: @STTLCU : I think regex is better option than explode, and it is simple regex

Comment: Regex is not meant to be simple, but to be mighty. Ergo regex is never simple!

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<?php
    $string="life really suck";
    list($firstName, $middlename, $lastName) = explode(" ", $string);
    echo $firstName; 
    echo $middlename;   
    echo $lastName;  
?>
```